# Configure restmod for submodule in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

So I have a main module `app` defined as

```
app = angular.module("app", ['app.social_accounts', 'restmod'])
```

which has its `restmod` module configured:

```
app.config(function(restmodProvider) {
    restmodProvider.rebase({
    $config: {
        primaryKey: "id",
        style: "ams",
        urlPrefix: "/app/"
    }
  });
});
```

and it works as expected: request were sent to `http://localhost:8000/app/...`

Now I want to use `restmod` in the submodule `app.social_accounts`, by doing

```
app = angular.module("app.social_accounts", ['restmod'])

app.config(function(restmodProvider) {
    restmodProvider.rebase({
    $config: {
        primaryKey: "id",
        style: "ams",
        urlPrefix: "https://graph.facebook.com/"
    }
  });
});
app.factory("Album", ["restmod", function(restmod){
    Album = restmod.model("/me/albums/")
    return {
        "get": function(){Album.$search()}
    }
}])
```

namely I want to use absolute `url` in the submodule `app.social_accounts`.

But when I inject `Album` (registered under `app.social_accounts`) into a `controller` `DashboardCtrl` under `app`, the request were sent to `http://localhost:8000/app/me/albums/`.

So I wonder what is happening here and how to achieve a separate `url` for `restmod` under `app.social_accounts`?

Answer (score 2):

Any configuration defined with `restmodProvider` is global for `restmod` irrespective of the module it's used in. So in your example above, the `urlPrefix` defined in the `app.social_accounts` module is being overwritten by the configuration in the `app` module.

In order to achieve the behaviour you expect, you can override the configuration on a per model basis:

```
angular.module('app.social_accounts', ['restmod'])

  .factory('Album', function(restmod) {
     var Album = restmod.model('/me/albums')
       .mix({
         $config: {
           urlPrefix: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
         }
       });
   });
```

If you require the configuration in more than one model within a module, a mixin can be used to keep things DRY:

```
.factory('restmodConfigSocial', function(restmod) {
  return restmod.mixin({
    $config: {
      urlPrefix: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    }
  });
})

.factory('Album', function(restmod) {
  var Album = restmod.model('/me/albums').mix('restmodConfigSocial');
});
```